# How to get the Performance Log of another tab from Selenium using Python?

Tags: python, selenium, logging

I'm using Selenium with Python API and Chrome to do the followings:

1. Collect the Performance Log;
2. Click some `<a, target='_blank'>` tags to get into other pages;

For example, I click a `href` in Page 'A', which commands the browser opens a new window to load another URL 'B'.

But when I use `driver.get_log('performance')` to get the performance log, I can only get the log of Page 'A'. Even though I switch to the window of 'B' as soon as I click the `href`, some log entries of the page 'B' will be lost.

So how can I get the whole performance log of another page without setting the target of `<a>` to '_top'?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I think it is because the driver does not immediately switch to a new window.

I switched to page "B" and reloaded this page, then uses `get_log` and it worked.